# regex find all occurence of content containing numbers surrounded by double asterisk

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have this:
`const str = "hello **Tom**, it's currently **19h25**. Here is **19** things found during the **last 2 hours** by **John1**"`

I need to find all occurence of content surrounded by double asterisk where there are numbers in the content.

I would like `str.match(regex)` to return `['19h25', '19', 'last 2 hours', 'john1']`. But not `**Tom**` because there is no number in the content.

I have try a regex like this `/\*{2}(.*\d)\*{2}/g` but it doesn't work.

Edit: There is no asterisk `*` inside both `**`

Comment: Can there be any `*` inside `**` and `**`? If not, use `/\*{2}([^\d*]*\d[^*]*)\*{2}/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\*{2}([^\d*]*\d[^*]*)\*{2}/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Frich/1)

**Details**

- `\*{2}` - a `**` substring
- `([^\d*]*\d[^*]*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^\d*]*` - 0+ chars other than digits and `*`
  - `\d` - a digit
  - `[^*]*` - 0+ chars other than `*`
- `\*{2}` - a `**` substring

JS demo:

```js
const str = "hello **Tom**, it's currently **19h25**. Here is **19** things found during the **last 2 hours** by **John1**";
const rx = /\*{2}([^\d*]*\d[^*]*)\*{2}/g;
let m, res = [];
while (m = rx.exec(str)) {
   res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
// or a one liner
console.log(str.match(rx).map(x => x.slice(2).slice(0, -2)));
```